# No container running for id xxxxxx when running apache beam go sdk examples

Tags: docker, apache-spark, go, sdk, apache-beam

I want to run grades example proposed by apache beam go sdk using spark runner on a spark cluster with one master and two slaves(spark2.4.5 version ). However I get the following error. I do not figure the main problem because ssh and docker are installed and running.

````
```Failed to retrieve staged files: failed to retrieve /tmp/staged in 3 attempts: failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/worker
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/worker
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/worker
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/worker
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = 
21/09/19 11:01:47 WARN BlockManager: Putting block rdd_2_1 failed due to exception org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container running for id 
Driver commanded a shutdown
apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container running for id xxxxxxxxx
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at  ```
````

I run the job service endpoint using the following command :

`docker run --net=host apache/beam_spark_job_server:latest --spark-master-url=spark://master:7077  --artifacts-dir /tmp/beam-artifact-staging`

And I run it using the following command :
`grades -runner=spark -endpoint=localhost:8099 -job_name=gradetest`
for the stderr spark log, I got the following :

````
23/09/20 10:06:22 INFO Executor: Adding file:/opt/spark/work/app-20210920100619-0017/1/./beam-runners-spark-job-server.jar to class loader
23/09/20 10:06:22 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 0
23/09/20 10:06:22 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to master/192.168.1.*:44365 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
23/09/20 10:06:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 10.9 KB, free 366.3 MB)
23/09/20 10:06:22 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 0 took 97 ms
23/09/20 10:06:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 24.9 KB, free 366.3 MB)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/beam-artifact-staging/e40099113cf8136935edc839aa85487c0532034c0a63f8cbadd7fccac0f98ed0/1-go-worker (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:127)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.open(FileSystems.java:257)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.ArtifactRetrievalService.getArtifact(ArtifactRetrievalService.java:124)
    at ```
````

Comment: I found in some others questions that we need to share the same artifact staging volume in  apache beam. Could one explain this in more detail and could it be the main problem for the mentioned error ?

Comment: Can you include relevant flags or other configuration you're using when running your example pipeline, and when starting up the runner? This error is almost definitely happening on the Spark runner, but it will be difficult to figure out why without more configuration details.

Comment: @Daniel Oliveira The question is edited with more information.

Comment: Thanks. I unfortunately don't know a solution yet, but I'm almost certain the problem is that your Spark job server isn't receiving any artifacts because it's running in a docker container and therefore can't see the files on your local file system. I'm not 100% sure what the best practice is with the Spark runner, but I believe if you can find the job server in jar form and run it outside of docker on the same machine as your pipeline code, that would fix the issue. But that may not be possible depending on your use case.

Comment: I run it outside docker and I got another error posted as question in [69494877](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494877/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-type-when-running-g)

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because the Spark Job Server is running in a docker container separate from your pipeline construction code. What happens is that your pipeline construction code (i.e. the "grades" binary file) stages artifacts for the Job Server in `/tmp/beam-artifact-staging`, a directory on your local machine. The Job Server however is searching in that directory within the docker container, and doesn't find the files.

Unfortunately the Go SDK currently does not support running a dockerized Spark Job Server. In other SDKs the dockerized Spark Job Server is intended to be used when running a pipeline as an uber jar (basically packaging the user pipeline and all artifacts into one jar and sending everything to the docker container with the Job Server). This functionality is currently unavailable in the Go SDK.

The simplest alternative for you is to run the Job Server directly as a jar on your local machine. I believe it is indexed as a Maven artifact as [`org.apache.beam:beam-runners-spark-job-server`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-spark-job-server/2.32.0). This way it should have access to the artifacts directory.

Comment: I run it  the job using the jar by from beam source code by now i get the following error:  `org.apache.beam.runners.jobsubmission.JobInvocation: Error during job invocation d-root-1007234448-cdfa0f12_bdc1d573-5dd6-4c1f-96c2 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.emptyBindings()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;`
spark version is in Spark’s 2.x branch and greater than 2.4.0 as they supposed.

Comment: Could you please propose any help

Comment: Not 100% sure what's happening there, but the first thing I would check is that the version of Beam you built the runner jar from exactly matches the version you're using to write your pipeline. If all the versions are exactly the same then I'm not sure what else the problem is, and you may be better served creating a new question for that.