# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type. when running go example using apache beam spark runner

Tags: java, apache-spark, go, apache-beam, jackson-databind

I want to run [grades](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/go/examples/grades) example proposed by apache beam go sdk using spark runner on a spark cluster with one master and two slaves (spark2.4.5 version ). I start the job runner using `./gradlew :runners:spark:2:job-server:runShadow -PsparkMasterUrl=spark://localhost:7077` and run it using the following command : `grades -runner=spark -endpoint=localhost:8099 -job_name=gradetest`

However I get the following error.

```
2021/10/08 11:42:34  (): org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.emptyBindings()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;
   at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.beamExceptionFrom(SparkPipelineResult.java:73)
   at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(SparkPipelineResult.java:104)
   at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(SparkPipelineResult.java:92)
   at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineRunner.run(SparkPipelineRunner.java:199)
```

I assume that the problem can be from the spark job runner because i test another code using python and I get the same error.
Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: Can you share more context about the Spark job runner(Standalone, YARN, Mesos) as well as the initial launching application spark command? Link for the Apache Beam Golang code example will help to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Wytrzymały Wiktor the question is updated.

Comment: @Ipad Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Mdumanoj no regrettably.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, I was just looking into related issues.

Unfortunately the Spark 2 job-server was broken when bumping the Jackson version used in Beam. By default Spark loads classes from its own system classpath first. And that classpath contains a very outdated version of Jackson which is not compatible with Beam anymore.

While there is work-arounds to deal with that when submitting Beam Java apps to Spark, these - unfortunately - don't work for the Spark job-server. See
https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/23568 for more details.

Also, Spark 2 support has been deprecated in Beam.

I recommend running the job-server for Spark 3 instead.

```
./gradlew :runners:spark:3:job-server:runShadow -PsparkMasterUrl=spark://localhost:7077
```